# put html input values into javascript object

Tags: javascript, jquery

Why isn't this code giving me an object with the keys as the `id`s of the text inputs, and the values as the values of the text inputs?

JS

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('body').on('click', '#btn', function () {
        var address = {};
        $('input[type="text"].address').each(function (index, element) {
            address[element.id] = $(element).val();
        });
        console.log(address);
    });
});
```

HTML

```
  <input class="address" id="attn" value="john doe">
  <input class="address" id="address_1" value="1234 sample st">
  <input class="address" id="address_2" value="Suite 1">
  <input class="address" id="city" value="chicago">
  <input class="address" id="state" value="IL">
  <input class="address" id="zip" value="12345">
  <input class="address" id="country" value="US">
  <input type="button" id="btn" value="btn" />
```

[jsbin](http://jsbin.com/osufok/1/edit)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because your inputs don't have `type="text"` thus `$('input[type="text"].address')` is not returning anything.

It's better to add them to signify that the inputs are of type text.

Comment: However, even with it added, I'm still just getting object Object in the console. http://jsbin.com/osufok/2/edit

Comment: @thomas: expand it, and you will see its properties. Your example works for me.

Answer (score 2):

Your inputs do not have the `[type=text]` attribute, so your selector matches none of them. Simply remove it, or use the [`:text`](http://api.jquery.com/text-selector/) selector:

```
var address = {};
$(':text.address').each(function (index, element) {
    address[element.id] = element.value;
});
console.log(address);
```

([updated demo](http://jsbin.com/osufok/10/edit))

Answer (score 1):

The jQuery attribute selector (as well as browser query selectors) work with the DOM elements rather than their properties.  If you do not explicitly have the `type` attribute declaration on your the input elements, `$("[type]")` and `document.querySelector("[type]")` will not find the element even if its type *property* is `text` (http://jsfiddle.net/g76UC/).

The simplest solution is to add `type=text` to the input elements in your HTML.  Another is to use a different selector that does not require this attribute definition.  The final (and least desirable) would be to create a separate selector such as `:prop` that checks the element's type *property* instead.  However this already exists in the form of jQuery's `:text`.

Comment: Gotcha. Makes perfect sense. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Use `this`

```
 $('input.address').each(function () {      
        address[this.id]= $(this).val();
 });
```

Demo http://jsbin.com/osufok/12/edit

Comment: no idea why you got a downvote, but could you explain why using `this` would be better jquery's `each(index, element){}`? Thanks!

Comment: Well, its not better, but index and element is not needed in this situation

Answer (score 0):

Try out this one http://jsfiddle.net/adiioo7/TPYtg/

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#btn').on('click', function () {
        var address = {};
        $('.address').each(function (index, element) {
            address[element.id] = $(element).val();
        });
        console.log(address);
    });
});
```